# Function in while loop executes only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in javascript, and I'm trying to figure out why my while loop won't actually loop more than once, even though the condition is always met.

I have a function sending an API request:

```
var get_status = function(trid, count) {
            console.log(count);
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'theUrlHere',
                headers: {'headers'}
            }
            $http(req).success(function(data) {
                if (data.transaction_status != 'Pending') {
                       // do something with the data
                    console.log('true');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('False');
                    return false;
                }
            }).error(function(data) {
                      // show an error popup
                console.log('true');
                return true;
            })
        }
    };
```

I want to call this function until it returns true, so I call it this way:

```
var count = 0;
while (get_status(id, count) === false) {
    count += 1;
}
```

The count variable is just added to see how many times it loops, it stays at 0 even  though 'False' is displayed in the console.

Is there some behaviour I am misunderstanding here?

**EDIT** I understand why this won't work. My intention here is to display an iframe as long as the transaction status is pending. I thought of continually sending a request until the transaction status is something other then 'Pending', but I am aware there are more optimal ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_status()` function does not return a value.  Thus, it's return value is `undefined` which is falsey so your `while()` loop stops after the very first iteration.

The return statements you do have in your code are inside of callbacks and have nothing to do with the return value of `get_status()`.

---

What you are attempting to do is generally not a good design.  It appears that you want to run a given Ajax call over and over with no delay until you get the answer you want.  This will potentially hammer the destination server.

If you describe the problem you're really trying to solve, we could help come up with a better way to do this.  Worst case, you could poll the server with a time delay between requests.

If you wanted to poll every so often, you could do something like this:

```
function get_status(trid, count) {
    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'theUrlHere',
        headers: {'headers'}
    }
    return $http(req).then(function(data) {
        return data.transaction_status;
    });
}

function poll_status(callback) {
    function next() {
        get_status(...).then(function(status) {
            if (status === "Pending") {
                // poll once every two seconds
                setTimeout(next, 2000);
            } else {
                // status is no longer pending, so call the callback and pass it the status
                callback(status);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            callback(err);
        });
    }
    next();
}


poll_status(function(result) {
    // done polling here, status no longer Pending
});
```

Comment: Regarding your second point, what is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: @Guillaume if you want to "poll" the server, you can use the whilst method below, but `callback()` from within a `setTimeout` at a defined interval.

Comment: @Guillaume - as I've added to my answer, if you can describe more about the problem you're actually trying to solve, we can likely come up with a much better design than you are attempting.

Comment: @Guillaume - I added an option for polling.  I personally dislike polling (generally inefficient), but you haven't explained enough about your system to know how you might be able to this better than polling.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for your suggestion, I think this most accurately fits my intent here. I understand why polling is generally a bad method, however I don't have a better idea at the moment. I need to display an iframe on my page as long as the transaction status is pending, and the server gets the status from a third party. I cannot come up with a way other than polling the server every so often to check if the status has changed

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return from within an asynchronous callback, which won't work, unfortunately. Instead you'll want a module like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), specifically [whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst).

```
var count = 0;
var outcome = false;

async.whilst(
    function () { outcome = false; },
    function (callback) {
        count++;
        // Your code here, setting outcome instead of returning
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'theUrlHere',
            headers: {'headers'}
        }
        $http(req).success(function(data) {
            if (data.transaction_status != 'Pending') {
                outcome = true;
                callback();
            }
            else {
                outcome = false
                callback();
            }
        }).error(function(data) {
            outcome = true;
            callback();
        })    
    },
    function (err) {
        // All done!
    }
);
```

But really the behavior you're looking for is probably checking on a status at pre-defined intervals. In this case, adapting the code

```
var count = 0;
var outcome = false;

async.whilst(
    function () { outcome = false; },
    function (callback) {
        count++;
        // Your request stuff.
        setTimeout(function () {
           callback();
        }, 1000); // Waits one second to begin next request
    },
    function (err) {
        // All done!
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for this, I understand my mistake here, I'll take a look at this

Comment: This will absolutely hammer the destination server over and over.  This is nearly always a bad design.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP didn't ask about bad design. But this is better than the original - it'll only start a new requests once one is completed. As I mentioned in my comment, this is one of the best ways to structure this design and OP can just use a setTimeout if he wants.

Comment: Good answers offer good design choices.  Providing a literal answer to the question that is a bad design is an answer, just not a good answer.

Comment: @Guillaume I've updated to account for what is likely your use case.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's not at all a good Stack Overflow mindset, IMO. You don't make assumptions about people's intentions - you work within the context that they specify and provide alternatives if relevant. Your answer essentially said "you're doing stuff wrong" with no reference for fixing it.

Comment: @J4G thank you for your answer, I will try this method

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions about intentions.  Polling a server as rapidly as requests can be made is pretty much never a good design.  Imagine 100 clients all doing this at once. Your server probably can't even keep up with that.  Now imagine 10,000 clients all doing it.  Hammering any host repeatedly is just a poor design.  No assumptions needed to know that.   Glad to see you've added an option that has a time delay.  FYI, the StackOverflow mindset is to provide the "best answer", not just "an answer".  I was providing you feedback on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to deals with async calls, I'd create a recursive function which will call itself. (in this case `get_status` should return a promise)

**Code**

```
var count = 0, id = 1;//id should be some value
(function myCall(promise){}
   promise.then(function(data){
      count += 1;
      if(data)
        myCall(get_status(id, count)); //call function on conditon
   });
}(get_status(id, count))
```

Method(Returning Promise)

```
var get_status = function(trid, count) {
        console.log(count);
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'theUrlHere',
            headers: {'headers'}
        }
        //returning promise here
        return $http(req).then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            if (data.transaction_status != 'Pending') {
                   // do something with the data
                console.log('true');
                return true; //resolves the promise
            }
            else {
                console.log('False');
                return false; //resolves the promise
            }
        }, function(data) {
                  // show an error popup
            console.log('true');
            return true;
        })
    }
};
```